# Message was send for first time, Why I can't send message again (Android Socket Programming)

Tags: android, sockets, client, outputstream

I created socket programming class for client. Connection was made. Server send a message to client. Client can take messages from server. But client only an answer sends. Why? Is the outputstream wrong?

```
public class Message extends AsyncTask<byte[], Void, Void> {
        Socket s;
        public static byte[] recv;
    
    
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(byte[]... voids) {
            byte[] message = voids[0];
            try {
                s = new Socket(destIp, destPort);
                DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
                dos.writeInt(message.length);
                dos.write(message);
                dos.flush();
                InputStream inFromServer = s.getInputStream();
                DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(inFromServer);
    
                byte[] buffer = new byte[200];
                int read = 0;
                while ((read = in.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) != -1) {
    //                in.read(buffer);
                    recv = Arrays.copyOf(buffer, read);
                    Context context = getContext();
                    Intent intentManager = new Intent(context, ManagerService.class);
                    context.startService(intentManager);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: `Connection was made. Server send a message to client. ` That can be. You did not post server code so we have to take that for granted. But we see your client code. And the client also sends a message upon connection. That is a wrong protocol. Decide which of the two sends a message first. Then the other has to read a message first.

Comment: Because, you have outputstream write function out of the loop. Then clientt will send message only once. If you want the client to keep on sending messages and read back from server try including both write and read inside a loop accordingly.

Comment: can't check  whether a reply will be sent or not in loop @Liju

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this in the part I start asynctask

```
new MessageReceive().execute(sendData);
```

to

```
new MessageReceive().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR,sendData);
```